# code execution flow at server side(golang)

Tags: http, go, server

**how the code really executed at server side?**

**myslice** is my actual global variable and **/modify** is my route to modify the **myslice** slice
and server listening on port **3000** and ip address of **9.134.108.219** and just imagine my **scenario** user 1(alice) and user 2 (bob) access the server at **9.134.108.219:3000/modify** at same time what will happen if alice changed the **myslice** variable little earlier than bob using **Mutatefunction()**?,  do really affect bob's slice too? like when printing the **myslice** variable? i'm really confused how the code executed at server side, can someone explain in brief?

**remainder: below is example code**

```
   package main
        import (
          "log"
          "net/http"
        )

    var myslice = []int{1,2,3,4}
    func main() {
      mux := http.NewServeMux()
      mux.HanldeFunc("/modify",Mutatefunction)
      log.Println("Listening...")
      http.ListenAndServe(":3000", mux)
    }

    func Mutatefunction(){
       fmt.Println("mutating")
       fmt.Println(myslice) // reading before modifying
       myslice = []int{0,0,0}
       fmt.Println("completed")
    }
```

Comment: Yes, `myslice` is global for all callers. This code isn't valid, because it's a data race to modify `myslice` concurrently, you always need to serialize access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `http.ListenAndServe` runs, your program starts waiting. Every new connection creates a new goroutine, which ends up calling `MutateFunction` if the request path is correct. So, you will have multiple goroutines running `MutateFunction` at the same time. For your case `myslice` is a global variable, and it is shared by all the goroutines. If you're making changes to that slice, you have to make sure you serialize access to that slice using a `sync.Mutex`.

Comment: okay! if i used sync.Mutex  then other goroutines will wait for unlocking?

Comment: Yes, they will.